# Blazor Server-Side + Okta + IIS Server's internet access

Tags: okta, blazor-server-side

I'm having an issue where my website is not redirecting to Okta when a client is browsing. same code hosted on my dev machine works properly. Okta applications are properly configured (Okta production and OktaPreview for testing). The only difference is that the server VM is not allowed to browse internet. We cannot use search engine or download anything ON the server. Is it possible that this lack of local internet on the IIS server is playing a role in the Blazor Server-Side app not doing anything when user clicks "Login"? The user sees a spinning wheel and the  template is shown instead of any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, even the user's click on a button is execute at server side. So, internet access had to be enabled for all Okta domain on server side and the client is now properly redirected to Okta for SSO.